# Stackoverflow.com web/database server specs

Tags: discussion, database, web, server

What are the specs of the Stackoverflow web server(s) and db server(s)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which tools and technologies were used to build the Trilogy?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-were-used-to-build-the-trilogy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The team has been very generous with information on their HW stack on [the blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/server/). Older posts are more HW focused.